# $ is undedined in Mvc4 view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an error in JSConsole saying `$` is undefined. However when I look at the page source, I see jQuery is included but it is included at the end of the page.

### BundleConfig

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
```

### _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

### View

```
@model MvcWebAPI.Models.ComputerStatus

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         alert('Hi');
     });
 </script>
 <h2>Index</h2>
```

### Rendered Source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert('Hi');
    });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your scripts in your view are not being placed in the scripts section.  Make sure you wrap those in

```
@section scripts
{
     <script>...</script>
}
```

Comment: thank you. This is the right solution. It adds my scripts at the end of the page. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your body to this will solve the problem

```
<body>
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @RenderBody()       
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: thank you. i know it is a best practice to render JS at the end of the page and thats the default layout in Mvc4 view. Am i missing something to make it work with with scripts rendered at the end of the page?

Comment: you cannot use a function/object/whatever in a script tag unless it is defined in the current tag or previously included scripts (I'm ignoring scripts dynamically loaded via javascript here but even there it's essentially the same concept; you can never use anything that hasn't been loaded yet.)

Comment: There is a performance gain referencing a js library as close to the bottom of the page as you can.  However, the page loads top down, so jquery must be loaded before you can use it.

Comment: To clarify further. you could always try adding your own window loaded DOM event handler (so it executes after your script has been loaded or DOMReady event (not so standard, IIRC), or your own dynamic script loader with a "script loaded" event that can be subscribed to, and then use jQuery after that... but something had to define those things before they could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your _ViewStart is pointing to:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If this is the case, then you can take out the script tag on the page.  The problem could be that the file is not being loaded on document ready and thus, you get the error. If you don't have a _ViewStart, just make sure your view is pointing to the _Layout for styling.

[EDIT]
Also try putting your script tag on the head or anywhere else besides the end of the document. It's a thing the loading of the document see if that helps.

Hope it helps.